# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am new to Reactjs and while writing anything on editor it shows  **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')** error.

I am using the react-draft library as a text editor.
My code is like this.

I am using this code because I want to add more editors when the add button is clicked.

```
 const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([{description: "" }])
    const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        const list = [...inputList];
        list[index][name] = value;
        setInputList(list);
    };



<Editor
   toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
    wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
  editorClassName="editorClassName"
wrapperStyle={{ width: 800, border: "1px solid black" }}
   name="description"
  value={x.description}
   onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)}
      />
```

when I type anything on the text field it shows **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')** error

Comment: can you create a codesandbox with the issue you are facing for easy debugging

Answer (score 0):

Please try it

```
const { name, value } = e.target;   
     setArr((prev) => {
    return [{ ...prev, name: value }];
  });
```